# To create a login at the AWS amplify React Application

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito, aws-amplify, aws-userpools

How to create a login at the AWS amplify React application, and the user can login with both their mobile number (password less) based on OTP and their Google Gmail (SSO). that user can already register in the AWS Cognito user pool.

I am trying to create a login based on the user's mobile number.

Comment: We need more specific information about what's wrong. Please describe what you're doing, show your code as a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), and clearly explain what's not working about your attempt. We're more than happy to then help :)